# SQL - Better approach for total records count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have written a query where I am fetching the records as well as total records count. I have two approaches in mind but can't figure out which one is better and less expensive

First with multiple cte's

```
;with allRecords as 
(
   -- query fetching all the records with many joins
),
recordsCount as 
(
    select count(*) as RecordsCount from allRecords
)
select * from allRecords, recordsCount
```

Second approach, using cte and cross join

```
;with allRecords as 
(
   -- query fetching all the records with many joins
)
select *, c.totalRecords from allRecords 
cross join (select count(*) as totalRecords from allRecords) c
```

I personally felt very minor better performance in second approach.

So in first approach, does second cte is called everytime for all the records of first cte or it just runs once when first cte finishes? Then I think there is no problem using first approach.

Suggestions please!

Comment: not sure I completely understand the question, but wouldn't analytic function work for you? `COUNT(*) OVER()`

Comment: @mcha Initially I used that only, but that is taking hell lot of time and so I switched to CTE's

Comment: interesting, have you succeed to achieve better performance with the other methods?

Comment: @mcha  - Yes the two approaches I mentioned worked lot faster than that

Answer (score 0):

A this approach would be to use `COUNT` with `OVER`:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER()
FROM --- rest of the query here
```

Comment: I was initially using `count over` but that is taking a lot more time than this one, my both approaches takes around 1-2 seconds while when I use count over it takes 26 secs

Answer (score 0):

Idea -1

```
sp_MSforeachtable 'sp_spaceused "?"'
```

Idea -2

```
sp_MSforeachtable 'select ''?'' Tablename, count(*) ''Rows'' from ?';
```

Idea -3

```
SELECT object_name(id), rows
FROM sysindexes
WHERE indid IN (0, 1)
```